# How to properly get data from recyclerView to an Activity from which RV was set?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an `Activity`, which has a `RecyclerView` and save `Button`. Each item (football match) of the `RecyclerView` contains some text (name of teams) and `EditText`, where user enters data (actually enters a score of the match). My goal is to save those scores to the list in the `Activity`, when user clicked on save button.

I read the similar question ([How can I return data from a RecyclerView adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918214/how-can-i-return-data-from-a-recyclerview-adapter)), the difference is that I need to get data from editText, not from checkBox(which is easy to check by clickListeners in `onBindViewHolder` method in `Adapter`)

So I made it on my way and it's works. I implemented this method, which actually get particular item from `LinearLayoutManager` and then get data from `EditText` .

```java
    private List<Bet> getNewUserBets() {
        View betView;
        Bet betItem;
        EditText userBet1;
        EditText userBet2;

        int numberOfMatches = rvMatchesAdapter.getItemCount();
        List<Bet> bets = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMatches; i++)
        {
            betItem = rvMatchesAdapter.getItem(i);
            betView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(i);
            userScore1 = (EditText) betView.findViewById(R.id.result1);
            userScore2 = (EditText) betView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
            //here i checked whether the editText is empty and other stuff
            bets.add(betItem);
        }
        return bets;
    }
```

But I was wondering if I made this on a good way. In my opinion there are two approach:

1. Separate logic. Implement a method in `Adapter` (probably in `onBindViewHolder`), which get data from `EditText`(entered by user). So logic about views should be in `Adapter`. And in `Activity` just call this method (like `getAdatper().`), when user presses a save button. So `Activity` doesn't know anything about views (what's is going on in `Adapter`).
2. Like I did. Make whole logic in `Activity`, which in my opinion is worse than approach described at number 1.

So in which way should I solve this task? And if 1 method is better, how should I get data from `EditText` directly from `Adapter`. Or maybe there is another approach(solution) to make this done. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to use `TextWatcher` in `ViewHolder` method in `Adapter`, which get data from `EditText`, at the moment when those `EditText`'s are changed. Add this data to `ArrayList` in `Adapter` of Bets and then use this ArrayList (which is public) in `Activity`