# Select from adapter Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I want to implement this UI to make the user select one branch at a time.
What I'm doing now is setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds for the text in each item when the user selects it.

[image]

The issues are "If I select item number 1 and then selected item number 4, how can I remove the selection from the item number 1? I don't want to click the item number 1 again to remove the selection"

**Note that this screen makes the user select only one item.**

This is my code in Kotlin But it is OK if you suggest a solution in JAVA:

```
var selectedBranch = false
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.packageNumber.text = branches?.get(position)?.nameEn ?: ""
    check = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_select_branch)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        if(!selectedBranch) {
        holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, check, null)
            selectedBranch = true
        }
        else {
            holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
            selectedBranch = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your list add a flag isSelected with every item. And on selection of any item set isSelected false for all other items and call notifyDataSetChange on adapter. Also show your tick mark based on isSelected flag from the list

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651847/4232337

Comment: @Arshad if you can show me an example it would be great!

Comment: @Abdulrahman NSimon has given a good reference. check this answer of that query it explain exactly what I told https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020046/3136282

Comment: See this one also   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030776/1427776

Comment: @Abdulrahman try my solution

Answer (score 1):

1.Create One `Model` Class which contain

```
String text;
boolean isTextSelected;
```

2.On Click of item in adapter, `Update` your model class 'isTextSelected' field.

3.`Notify` your adpater.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this "selectedBranch" Boolean in your data class which you have used as a model in branches list

add this code to your bindViewHolder

```
if(branches?.get(position)?.selectedBranch == false) {

            holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
        }
        else {
            holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, check, null)
      }

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

    if(branches?.get(position)?.selectedBranch == false) {

        holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, check, null)
        branches?.get(position)?.selectedBranch = true
    }
    else {
        holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
        branches?.get(position)?.selectedBranch = false
    }
 adapter.notifyDatasetChange()
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a flag in each item, **`Use integer variable to store the last clicked position`**

Initially `clickedposition=-1`

Use this in your adapter class,

```
if(position == clickedposition) {

        holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, check, null)
}
else {
        holder.packageNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)

}

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
      clickedposition=position;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one boolean variable into branche pojo class.
then make interface into adapter to handle click event into recyclerview like below code ..

```
  onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(Branch str);//pass your object types.
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    Branch data=branches.get(position);
    if (data.isSelected()){
    }
    else{

    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
        }
    });
}
```

then after adapter bind into recycler view call below code..

```
recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Branch str)
        {
            str.setSelected(true);
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
```